# Changing div width on click and then back

Tags: jquery

How can I change a div's width by clicking it and then back to original width clicking it again? Bonus point if any change in width is animated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css transitions together with jQuery for this. 
Just set a class with jQuery when click on `div` and let CSS do the animation.

See fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/J3FTN/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this jquery code :

```
$('div').toggle(function() {
$(this).animate({width: '100px'}, 1000)
}, function() {
$(this).animate({width: ''}, 1000)
})
```